# not able to overlay content over JQuery Video Plugin - JQuery.videoBG

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am using the jquery plugin https://github.com/sydlawrence/jquery.videoBG to play video in the background.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>RhytmicWorks Software</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.videoBG/jquery.videoBG.js"></script>
    <script src="js/videobg.js"></script> 


</head>
<body>

<div class="common">
    This is inside testing div
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.css

```
.common{
    position:absolute;
    height:30%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: pink;
    z-index:1;

}
```

videobg.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('body').videoBG({
        position:"fixed",
        zIndex:-1,
        mp4:'assets/Rhythm.mp4',
        webm:'assets/Rhythm.webm',
        opacity:1,
        fullscreen:true,
    });

});
```

I can play the video in the background, but the div with the 'common' class can only be seen if I dont load the plugin

Answer (score 0):

I know this seems pretty obvious, but, have you try adding a z-index positive value to your common div?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried adding z-index ab adding the property for common in app.css. Still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Change the css to

```
.common {
  height: 30%;
  width: 100% !important;
  background-color: pink;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This will surely work

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/6uwvx974/

http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/6uwvx974/1/